# Java byte code instrumentation with an external library

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm

I am using ASM with java agents. I have the following problem.
Whenever I see a "PUTFIELD" instruction within a method call, I want call a method from my agent library.

```
if (opcode == PUTFIELD) {       
    super.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKESTATIC, "instrumenter/Util", "debug", "()V");
```

`Util` is a class defined by me with a static `debug` method. It stays in my agent.jar

`java -javagent:agent.jar -jar test.Test` works as I expected.

However, when I test this agent with some other jar files I got following error.
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: instrumenter/Util`

I suspect this occurs due to concurrency. Since the programs which create this error are mostly multi-threaded.

Comment: typo? or do you really mean `instur/Util`?

Answer (score 1):

you could try to use `-bootclasspath/p` instead of `-jar`, probably, something is loaded too early for your util-class or some classloader-issue (e.g. a different (custom) classloader which cannot access your jar). if you put your jar into the bootclasspath, at least this source of defect is eliminated